# Haskell Error lexical error in string/character literal at character ' \r'

Tags: haskell

Hello I'm trying to write a program that converts markdown to HTML, I understand there is Pandoc but my project is writing it out manually. I have it completed or at least I think i Do but I'm getting the following error Haskell Error `lexical error in string/character literal at character ' \r'` I have no Idea as to what is referring to, any help in pointing it out would be great. Thanks So update: I changed a few things with misc symbols and the error I get now is `hs.38:17: Not in scope 'str'` and as I was working through the thing it has repeatedly kept pointing at line 38 in which I cannot figure out what the issue is as it ignores the same exact thing in the previous function

```
module Main
(
convertToHTML,
convertSpecialChar,
main
) where

import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.IO
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split

eof = "</body></html>"

convertToHTML :: String -> String
convertToHTML x = specialTags $ headings $ endings $ beginnings $ replace "---"<hr>" x


convertSpecialChar :: String -> String
ConvertSpecialChar x = (convertLessThan $ convertAmpersand $ convertGreaterThan x)++eof
    where
        convertLessThan str = concat [if c =='<' then '&lt" else [c] | c <- str]
        convertAmpersand str = concat [if c == '&' then "&amp" else [c] | c <- str]
        convertGreaterThan str = concat [if c =='>' then "&gt" else [c] | c <- str]

beginnings :: String -> String
beginnings str = unwords $ map tag ch
   where
   tag x
    | isPrefixOf "**" x = "<strong>" ++ (tail $ tail x)
    | isPrefixOf "__" x = "<strong>" ++ (tail $ tail x)
    | isPrefixOf  "_" x = "<em>" ++ (tail x)
    | isPrefixOf "*" x = "<em>" ++ (tail x)
    | isPrefixOf  "^" x = "<p>" ++ (tail x)
    | isPrefixOf "---" x = replace "---" "<hr>"
    | otherwise = x
ch =splitOn " " str

replace :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
replace old new x = intercalate new (splitOn old x)

endings :: String -> String
endings str = unwords $ map tag ch
   where
       tag x
    | isInfixOf "**" x = replace "**" "</strong>" x
    | isInfixOf "__" x = replace "__" "</strong>" x
    | isInfixOf "_"  x = replace "_" "</em>" x
    | isInfixOf "*" x = replace "*" "</em>" x
    | isInfixOf "^" x = replace "^" "</p>" x
    | isInfixOf "---" x = replace "---" "<hr>" x
    | otherwise = x
   ch = splitOn " " str

headings str = unlines $ map heads (lines str)
   where
      heads x
    | isPrefixOf "######" x = "<h6>" ++ (numTail 6 x) ++ "</h6>"
    | isPrefixOf "#####" x = "<h5>" ++ (numTail 5 x) ++ "</h5>"
    | isPrefixOf "####" x = "<h4>" ++ (numTail 4 x) ++ "</h4>"
    | isPrefixOf "###" x = "<h3>" ++ (numTail 3 x) ++ "</h3>"
    | isPrefixOf "##" x = "<h2>" ++ (tail $ tail x) ++ "</h2>"
    | isPrefixOf "#" x = "<h1>" ++ (tail x) ++ "</h1>"
    | otherwise = x

specialTags str = unlines $ map tags (lines str)
   where
      tags x
    | isPrefixOf "[code]" x = "<blockquote><pre><code>" ++ (numTail 6 x)
    | isSuffixOf "[code]" x = (numInit 6 x) ++ "</code></pre></blockquote>"
    | otherwise = x

numTail :: Int -> String -> String
numTail _ [] = []
numTail 1 str = tail str
numTail x str = tail $ (numTail (x-1) str)

numInit :: Int-> String -> String
numInit _ [] = []
numInit 1 str = init str
numInit x str = init $ (numInit (x-1) str)

main = do
   args <- getArgs
   let (infile,outfile) = (\\(x:y:ys) -> (x,y)) args
   putStrLn $ "Input file: " ++ infile
   putStrLn $ "Output file: " ++ outfile
   contents <- readFile infile
   let contentlines = unlines $ tail $ lines contents
   let title = head $ lines contents
   let header = "<!DOCTYPE html> <head>" ++ "<meta http-equiv = \\"Content-type\\"content=\\"text/html; charset=utf-8\\" />" ++ "<title>" ++title++"</title>" ++"</head><body>"
   writeFile outfile $ convertToHTML $ header ++ convertSpecialChar contentlines
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On line 17, you are missing a double quote. I suppose `replace "---"<hr>" x` should read `replace "---" "<hr>" x`.

The whole declaration of your function `convertToHTML` will then read

```
convertToHTML :: String -> String
convertToHTML x = specialTags $ headings $ endings $ beginnings $ replace "---" "<hr>" x
```

#### So why did the compiler complain about a character `'\r'`?

The first stage in compiling a Haskell module is lexical analysis, in which your program text is broken up into tokens that are then processed by the parser. In your case, lexical analysis failed because the assumed a new string literal was started by `" x`. Then it encountered the end of line 17 without the literal begin properly terminated with a closing double quote or any indication of the string literal being a [*multiline* string literal](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/characters-strings-and-escaping-rules.html#id689881). As this is illegal lexical syntax, it then complained about the encountered end of line (`'\r'`).

Admittedly, it would have been more helpful if the error message would have made explicit mention of an nonterminated string literal.

In any case, an editor with syntax-highlighting support for Haskell would probably have hinted at the problem early on already. ;)

#### Indentation

The issue you are then having with the variable `str` not being in scope in your local definition of  `ch` is due to layout. Make sure that `ch` is indented at the same level as the preceding definition of `tag`. That is, instead of

```
beginnings :: String -> String
beginnings str = unwords $ map tag ch
   where
   tag x
    | isPrefixOf "**" x = "<strong>" ++ (tail $ tail x)
    | isPrefixOf "__" x = "<strong>" ++ (tail $ tail x)
    | isPrefixOf  "_" x = "<em>" ++ (tail x)
    | isPrefixOf "*" x = "<em>" ++ (tail x)
    | isPrefixOf  "^" x = "<p>" ++ (tail x)
    | isPrefixOf "---" x = replace "---" "<hr>"
    | otherwise = x
ch =splitOn " " str
```

you should write something like

```
beginnings :: String -> String
beginnings str = unwords $ map tag ch
  where
    tag x
      | isPrefixOf "**" x = "<strong>" ++ (tail $ tail x)
      | isPrefixOf "__" x = "<strong>" ++ (tail $ tail x)
      | isPrefixOf  "_" x = "<em>" ++ (tail x)
      | isPrefixOf "*" x = "<em>" ++ (tail x)
      | isPrefixOf  "^" x = "<p>" ++ (tail x)
      | isPrefixOf "---" x = replace "---" "<hr>"
      | otherwise = x
    ch = splitOn " " str
```

Remember, in Haskell, [the layout of your code matters](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation).

Comment: Thank you for that! I hate missing a character I even went line by line looking for any missing character and fixed a bunch of them but apparently I didn't get all of them i do also know of the other character '&lt" and have that fixed but now all the errors keep referring to Line 38 in the endings function with    ch = splitOn " " str stating Not in scope 'str' but It looks right to me

Comment: @Abstract3000 That's a layout issue: make sure that your definition for `ch` is indented as much as the definition for `tag`, right above it.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help I apologize I am very weak in this language though I truly appreciate you taking the time to look at it. I am very very new to haskell meaning I'm in a 2 credit course that teaches us the very basics of functions and we have a professor that only gives us the minimal info, then assigns problems (^like this) that requires allot of research outside of the classroom. The professor refuses to help us with any of the code and his famous phrase "Google is your best friend" Thank you again